# NextJS Router & Jest: How can I mock router change event

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, next.js

I am using `next-routes` and in my React component I am using below `useEffect` code block to detect `Router` change event:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // THIS BLOCK WILL BE EXECUTED WHEN THE COMPONENT IS ALREADY MOUNTED AND SCREEN WOULD BE REDNDERED IN WHEN ROUTED CLIENT SIDE
  const handleRouterChangeComplete = url => {
    // console.log('INNNN handleRouterChangeComplete url = ', url);
    // MY REST OF THE LOGIC HERE
  };

  // THIS BLOCK WILL BE EXECUTED WHEN THE SCREEN WOULD BE REDNDERED IN WHEN ROUTED CLIENT SIDE
  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouterChangeComplete);
  return () => {
    Router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouterChangeComplete);
  };
}, []);
```

I am using `jest` to write unit test case for this component and facing below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

      183 |
      184 |     // THIS BLOCK WILL BE EXECUTED WHEN THE SCREEN WOULD BE REDNDERED IN WHEN ROUTED CLIENT SIDE
    > 185 |     Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouterChangeComplete);
```

Can anybody please help me with mocking the `Router Change` event?
Thanks

Comment: Mock the event of Router.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I do that. Any code snippet?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wondering how to do the same thing

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is stuck with testing the Router change events in nextjs here is an example.

### Short Answer

You can use `Router.events.emit` to emit the event from your test then assert the callback you are expecting to get fired.

### Long Answer

Following is the scenario I am using in the example, however you can modify it to your needs.

**Scenario:** In my main app, I am using [NProgress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nprogress) to display a progress bar on each route change. The custom app looks like this

```
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());

export default CustomApp() {
   ...
}
```

Now, in my test, I want to test that the callbacks are called appropriately. The jest test looks like this:

```
import Router from 'next/router;
import NProgress from 'nprogress;
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import CustomApp from 'pages/_app';

const mockStart = jest.spyOn(NProgress, 'start');
const mockDone = jest.spyOn(NProgress, 'done');

it('starts nprogress on router change start', () => {
  render(<CustomApp />)
  Router.events.emit('routeChangeStart');
  expect(mockStart).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('ends nprogress on router change complete', () => {
  render(<CustomApp />)
  Router.events.emit('routeChangeComplete');
  expect(mockDone).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the relevant change event by using `Router.events.emit('event-name')`;

The code was taken from the [router implementation](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/c24daa21722fadfce2d1d561ce65ecc0efa6a7ea/packages/next/next-server/lib/router/router.ts#L394).

Comment: Sorry, mate. But I can't figure out how to use this in my jest unit test case.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `useRouter` hook from `next/router` in my implementation.

```
import { FunctionComponent, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
  // handle route change
  return `handling url - ${url}`
};

const Component: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);

  // do other things
};
```

and doing the following in my test to mock `useRouter`:

```
jest.mock('next/router');

let eventName;
let routeChangeHandler;

useRouter.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    events: {
      on: jest.fn((event, callback) => {
        eventName = event;
        routeChangeHandler = callback;
      }),
      off: jest.fn((event, callback) => {
        eventName = event;
        routeChangeHandler = callback;
      }),
    },
  };
});
```

and my test looks like

```
it('should call the required functions', () => {
    render(<Component />);

    expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(eventName).toBe('routeChangeComplete'); 
    expect(routeChangeHandler).toBeDefined();

    expect(routeChangeHandler('/')).toBe('handling url - /');

    useRouter().events.on('onEvent', routeChangeHandler);
    expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(eventName).toBe('onEvent');

    useRouter().events.off('offEvent', routeChangeHandler);
    expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    expect(eventName).toBe('offEvent');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I based my answer off of a lengthy thread here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479.

Hopefully someone can swoop in and make a better answer by saying how it works or improving for best practices.

```
// _app.test.js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponentThatUsesRouter from '../components/MyComponentThatUsesRouter';

//Router mock
const useRouter = jest.spyOn(require("next/router"), "useRouter");

describe('MyComponentThatUsesRouter', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    // hypothetical prop possibly not needed
    const myprop1={red, blue, orange}
    // Specific mock default values - change as needed
    useRouter.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
        basePath: '/',
        pathname: '/',
        route: '/',
        query: {},
        asPath: '/',
        push: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
        replace: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
        reload: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
        prefetch: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
        back: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
        beforePopState: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
        isFallback: false,
        events: {
          on: jest.fn(),
          off: jest.fn(),
          emit: jest.fn(),
        },
    }));
    // Your component that is using Router
    render(<MyComponentThatUsesRouter prop1={myprop1} />)

  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way on this github issue

*Just store the callback into a variable so you can "trigger" the event whenever you wish.*

```js
let routeChangeComplete;
Router.default.events.on = jest.fn((event, callback) => {
    routeChangeComplete = callback;
  });
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7586