# Mocking NextJS router events with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, next-router

I am trying to mock NextJS router events with Jest. Found a relevant resource right here at [NextJS router & Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961579/nextjs-router-jest-how-can-i-mock-router-change-event). The implementation there is very similar to mine.

However, the solution mentioned there is not working for me.

My test is below:

```
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import FavoritesPage from 'pages/user/favorites';
import configureStore, { MockStore } from 'redux-mock-store';
import storeInitialState from '__tests__/unit/support/storeInitialState';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { RequestStates } from 'types/State';
import useAdSetup from 'lib/hooks/useAdSetup';

const mockRequestState = RequestStates.Finished;

jest.mock('lib/Auth');
jest.mock('lib/EventLogger');
jest.mock('lib/hooks/useAdSetup');

jest.mock('lib/hooks/useFetchFavorites', () => {
  return (): { requestState: RequestStates } => {
    return {
      requestState: mockRequestState,
    };
  };
});

jest.mock('next/router');

const mockStore = configureStore();

let store: MockStore;

describe('when clicking the price drop subnav button', () => {
  let component: ReactWrapper;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    store = mockStore(storeInitialState);
    await waitFor(() => {
      component = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <FavoritesPage />
        </Provider>
      );
    });
    component.find('.price-drop-nav-item').simulate('click');
  });

  it('shows price drops', () => {
    let eventName;
    let routeChangeHandler;
    let useRouter = jest.fn();

    useRouter.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        events: {
          on: jest.fn((event, callback) => {
            eventName = event;
            routeChangeHandler = callback;
          }),
          off: jest.fn((event, callback) => {
            eventName = event;
            routeChangeHandler = callback;
          }),
        },
      };
    });
  
    expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.find('.price-drop-nav-item').hasClass('active')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Inside, my component just like the referenced example has the following:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleComplete: any = async (url: string) => {
      if (window) {
        await trackReturnToSeachClick(url);
      }
    };
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete);
    router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleComplete);

    // Cleanup event listeners
    return (): void => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete);
      router.events.off('routeChangeError', handleComplete);
    };
  }, [router]);
```

Unlike the referenced example, when I run my code, I am still getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found a bunch of relevant samples online. The most useful, as far as NextJS 11 goes was the thread at [vercel/next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/23034). Based on that, I was able to put together the working solution below:

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return ({
      route: '/',
      pathname: '',
      query: '',
      asPath: '',
      push: jest.fn(),
      events: {
        on: jest.fn(),
        off: jest.fn()
      },
      beforePopState: jest.fn(() => null),
      prefetch: jest.fn(() => null)
    });
  },
}));

const mockStore = configureStore();

let store: MockStore;

describe('when clicking the price drop subnav button', () => {
  let component: ReactWrapper;
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    store = mockStore(storeInitialState);

    const useRouter = jest.spyOn(require("next/router"), "useRouter");

    useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
      route: '/',
      pathname: '',
      query: '',
      asPath: '',
      push: jest.fn(),
      events: {
        on: jest.fn(),
        off: jest.fn()
      },
      beforePopState: jest.fn(() => null),
      prefetch: jest.fn(() => null)
    }));

    component = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <FavoritesPage />
        </Provider>
    );
    component.find('.price-drop-nav-item').simulate('click');
  });

  it('shows price drops', () => {
  
    // expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.find('.price-drop-nav-item').hasClass('active')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Nothing else worked for me. The test for `expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` is not working either. :)

Comment: There's also next-router-mock package https://github.com/scottrippey/next-router-mock

Answer (score 7):

I simply put this on the top-level of my test file before the `describe` call.

```js
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      pathname: '',
      // ... whatever else you you call on `router`
    };
  },
}));
```

Comment: This one fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you mock useRouter.

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  userRouter: jest.fn()
})
```

Then, you add a return value to your mock. We need events.on and events.off so we will return that.

```
test('some test', () => {
  useRouter.mockReturnValue({
    events: {
      on: () => {},
      off: () => {},
    }
  })
  render(<SomeComponent />)
  expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

That's all. There is no use in adding mocking function to the on method: `on: jest.fn()` because you can't access them. So dummy functions `() => {}` will do. If you wanted to test if events.on gets called with the correct values, do this:

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn()
}))

const mockOn = jest.fn()

test('some test', () => {
  useRouter.mockReturnValue({
    events: {
      on: mockOn,
      off: () => {},
    }
  })
  render(<SomeComponent />)
  expect(useRouter).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(mockOn).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(mockOn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some event', expect.any(Function))
})
```

I wrote more about [mocking next/router in an article on dev.to](https://dev.to/peterlidee/how-to-mock-next-router-with-jest-3p6b).