# next js testing issue with next router

Tags: next.js, react-testing-library

I am trying to writing unit test with react-testing-library for my project in nextjs but I have trouble with next router specially localization

```
const t = locale === 'fa' ? fa : en;
```

I face to this error while I run the test
Cannot destructure property 'locale' of 'router' as it is null.
any body have idea about this problem ?

Comment: have you configured your project for test? [read this](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing)

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia yes I did . some of my test passed

Comment: Try mocking `next/router` in your tests. See [Mocking NextJS router events with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125633/mocking-nextjs-router-events-with-jest).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to just mock the useRouter() like follow

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      locale: 'en'
      //You can add whatever keys that you required
    };
  }
}));
```

Place this above the "describe" block