# router.push from next/router is not a function when running jest test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am getting this error when trying to use next.router in jest:

```
TypeError: _router.default.push is not a function
> 17 |     router.push(url, undefined, { shallow: true, scroll });
```

this is how i have configured my jest testing (simplified):
jest.config.ts has

```
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest/setup/jest.mocks.ts'],
};
```

and jest.mocks.ts

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      route: '/',
      pathname: '',
      query: '',
      asPath: '',
      locale: 'no',
      push: jest.fn(),
      reload: jest.fn(),
      events: {
        on: jest.fn(),
        off: jest.fn(),
      },
      beforePopState: jest.fn(() => null),
      prefetch: jest.fn(() => null),
    };
  },
}));
```

my test file:

```
describe('ProductCardHoverElements', () => {
  test('trackhit callback', async () => {
    const trackHit = jest.fn();

    renderTest(() => (
      <MockedApolloProvider mocks={frameworkMock({})}>
        <ProductCardHoverElements
          product={productMock}
          currProduct={productMock}
          isMobileOrTablet={true}
          imageRef={imageRef}
          trackHit={trackHit}
          onInView={() => {}}
          parentHover={false}
        />
      </MockedApolloProvider>
    ));
    mockAllIsIntersecting(true);
    const emptyButton = screen.getByAltText(
      'Lang, kabelstrikket genser. Front. Model.',
    );
    fireEvent.click(emptyButton);
    expect(trackHit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

my ProductCardHoverElements.tsx is a component that runs a router.push() when the fireEvent.click() executed, in addition to a trackHit function passed as props. The test itself worked fine when i did not have router.push(), but having this function is crucial to navigate in NextJs. And in theory the next router is already mocked in jest.mocks.ts, i've tried mocking it again locally in the test itself but is still not working. Can anyone see whats wrong here?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125633/mocking-nextjs-router-events-with-jest) answer your question?